# Locate Metaio camera on a fixed position as gui texture + Display one object from the scene through that Metaio camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, metaio

1) I am a beginner to using Metaio in Unity, so my question is that is it possible to include two cameras on my scene: one is the main for 3D environment, and another camera (metaio camera) to display objects from Unity on the real world that must be fixed on the top wright corner as UI plane of my game. Something like in the picture below: 
[image]

2) Also, how to display on the metaio camera view on the scene instead of displaying all scene objects as shown in the image below, although I only attached one cube object under metaio tracker:
[image]

Any help or answers gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain better about question? what metaio means? i think you want to set stream received from a camera like webcam or phone camera to that plain? i think tehnically its possible. if i think right about your question let write your answer

Comment: Thank you virtouso for your comments. Yes, you're quite right. I mean that I would like to have an AR metaio camera to be fixed there at the corner. And when I point out to a QR code from that virtual world camera using my iPad for example, it should be appeared on the camera outcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to attach an script to that plain and add the code bellow to that script:

```
void Start() {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play();
    }
```

if you working for android you have to add camera permission to you manifest.
i think you need to work on it, because it doesnt work simply and you have to play with camera positions and to work very well.

this link shows you camera options that you have in unity:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

Comment: Thanks virtouso for your answer. This is working fine, but my query is specifically about how to deploy the metaio augmented reality camera using (metaioSDK prefab) provided by metaio sdk instead of just running the machine camera as you did. Thanks